# Passing data from a controller to a gridview fails with

Tags: php, gridview, yii2, yii-extensions, yii2-advanced-app

I have been trying to pass an array of model data from a controller to a gridview to a gridview but I get an error of:

```
The "query" property must be an instance of a class that implements the 
QueryInterface e.g. yii\db\Query or its subclasses.
```

This is the controller code:

```
 public function actionAddunits($id){

  $countUnits = Unitslocation::find()->where(['officelocationid'=>$id])->count();
    if(count($countUnits)>0){

   $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' =>Unitslocation::find()->where(['officelocationid'=>$id])->all()
    ]);

      return $this->render('assignunits', ['dataProvider'=>$dataProvider]);

    }else{
        return 0;
    }

}
```

The view (assignunits.php)

```
<?php
echo GridView::widget([
'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
'columns' => [
    // ...
    [
        'class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn',
        // you may configure additional properties here
    ],
],]);

?>
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ActivedataProvider` needs a `query`. In your case you send the result of the `query(all())`.

Remove `all()` in your `query`.

```
$query = Unitslocation::find()->where(['officelocationid'=>$id]);
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query,
]);
```